# Trying to install Kali linux but resolution is messed up

Tags: kali-linux

Not sure what exactly is going wrong. Im trying to install kali linux in graphical mode and this keeps happening before i can start to install it. I can't do anything other than move the blue line up and down but can't read the options.

any help is appreciated

[image: My screen during install]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Comment: Fixed by using rufus and setting it to a DD instead of ISO (when using usb)

Answer (score 1):

Try using a VGA connection to the monitor. Kali Installer might not support the resolution on your specific monitor yet until proper drivers are present after you've installed it. Also I would try to boot a live CD (USB) version of another distribution (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) to see if you get the same results.

Comment: Its on my laptop so the using different monitor won't work but will try a different distribution . thanks :)